# Help with navigation terminology for an audit application

Tags: terminology

We have a process where users complete surveys for a company. There are many surveys, spread over different facilities, the hierarchy can be detailed like this:

Contract > Facility > Audit

Although the audits will be filtered depending on the user and the users groups, a single user could have many audits available to them.

The platform is mobile (minimum viewport 320x480 (Samsung Galaxy Ace)) and may not always have a connection.

The question is this. When a user finishes an audit we want to offer them three options.

1. Sync Your Audit Data
2. Return to Audit List
3. Start a New Audit

Basically I'm not happy with the terminology of options 2 and 3.

Option 2 should return the user to the audit list within the same contract and facility to which they navigated prior to taking the audit they have just completed.

Option 3 should take them back to the contract list so they can start the process of drilling down to the audit they want to complete, again.

Appreciate this is quite subjective, but I've been mulling this for a good few hours now and can't get it quite right, so would appreciate some ideas and thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is about Audits, and the user knows the context is Audits there is no real use of repeating Audit in every option. Instead I'd use single words for each option making it easier/faster for the user to know where to go.

1. **<< Sync >>**
2. **<< List >>**
3. **<< Create >>**

Answer (score 0):

What about using icons , Sync, return, New

[image: Sync back new]

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the confusion with step 3 is explaining the action they are taking. Instead of Start A New Audit, the immediate action sounds like returning to the contract list, so is it more of a super back button - Back to Contracts?

It might help to look at your page flow and ask yourself (or coworkers) what actions you want to be able to take on each screen. Talking it out might give you the verbiage you want.

Answer (score 0):

A tree testing would be helpful for you. I was wondering if Contracts are only made with companies. Can user have also many contracts? If you want them to start again, Start New may be an option giving them no expectation on starting point. Or Can you not say Take new Contract? As you said it is very contextual. Hard to say without knowing more but card sorting and tree testing should help you with this.